# Linux script run with run-this-one doesn't work with docker

Tags: bash, docker

I'm experiencing an issue in which I run a command in a cronjob and want to make sure that it's not already being executed. I achieve that running as `run-one [command]` ([man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/run-one.1.html)).

If I want to cancel the already running command and force the new command to run, I run as `run-this-one [command]`.

At least this is what I expected, but if the command runs a docker container, the other process seems to be terminated (but isn't), the terminal shows `Terminated`, but continues to show the command output that is running in the container (but the commands after the container ends running are not executed). In this case, the command that runs `run-this-one` is not executed (not expected).

Example:

*/path/to/file.sh*

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

echo "sleep started..." >&2
docker run --rm alpine /bin/sh -c 'echo "sleep started inside..." && sleep 5 && echo "sleep ended inside..."'
echo "sleep ended..." >&2
```

If I run in a terminal window `sudo run-one /path/to/file.sh`, and then run in another terminal (before the previous command ends running) the command `sudo run-one /path/to/file.sh`, this command is not executed, as expected, and that command ends succesfully.

*Terminal1:*

```bash
user@host:/path$ sudo run-one /path/to/file.sh
sleep started...
sleep started inside...
sleep ended inside...
sleep ended...
user@host:/path$
```

*Terminal2:*

```bash
user@host:/path$ sudo run-one /path/to/file.sh
user@host:/path$
```

But if I run in a terminal window `sudo run-one /path/to/file.sh`, and then run in another terminal (before the previous command ends running) the command `sudo run-this-one /path/to/file.sh`, this command is not executed, which is **not** expected, and that command shows in the terminal `Terminated`, with the terminal showing `user@host:/path$`, but the output in the container still shows (the command is still running in the container created in the 1st terminal).

*Terminal1:*

```bash
user@host:/path$ sudo run-one /path/to/file.sh
sleep started...
sleep started inside...
Terminated
user@host:/path$ sleep ended inside...
# terminal doesn't show new input from the keyboard, but I can run commands after
```

*Terminal2:*

```bash
user@host:/path$ sudo run-this-one /path/to/file.sh
user@host:/path$
```

It works if the file is changed to:

*/path/to/file.sh*

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

echo "sleep started..." >&2
sleep 5
echo "sleep ended..." >&2
```

The above script file with docker was just an example, in my case it's different, but the problem is the same, and occurs independently of running the container with or without `-it`.

**Someone knows why this is happening? Is there a (not very complex and not very hackish) solution to this problem?** I've executed the above commands in Ubuntu 20.04 inside a VirtualBox machine (with vagrant).

**Update (2021-07-15)**

Based on *@ErikMD* comment and *@DannyB* answer, I put a trap and a cleanup function to remove the container, as can be seen in the script below:

*/path/to/test*

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -eou pipefail

trap 'echo "[error] ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}:$LINENO" >&2; exit 3;' ERR

RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color

function error {
    msg="$(date '+%F %T') - ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}:${BASH_LINENO[0]}: ${*}"
    >&2 echo -e "${RED}${msg}${NC}"
    exit 2
}

file="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"

command="${1:-}"

if [ -z "$command" ]; then
    error "[error] no command entered"
fi

shift;

case "$command" in
    "cmd1")
        function cleanup {
            echo "cleaning $command..."
            sudo docker rm --force "test-container"
        }

        trap 'cleanup; exit 4;' ERR

        args=( "$file" "cmd:unique" )
        echo "$command: run-one ${args[*]}" >&2
        run-one "${args[@]}"
        ;;
    "cmd2")
        function cleanup {
            echo "cleaning $command..."
            sudo docker rm --force "test-container"
        }

        trap 'cleanup; exit 4;' ERR

        args=( "$file" "cmd:unique" )
        echo "$command: run-this-one ${args[*]}" >&2
        run-this-one "${args[@]}"
        ;;
    "cmd:unique")
        "$file" "cmd:container"
        ;;
    "cmd:container")
        echo "sleep started..." >&2
        sudo docker run --rm --name "test-container" alpine \
            /bin/sh -c 'echo "sleep started inside..." && sleep 5 && echo "sleep ended inside..."'
        echo "sleep ended..." >&2
        ;;
    *)
        echo -e "${RED}[error] invalid command: $command${NC}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

If I run `/path/to/test cmd1` (`run-one`) and `/path/to/test cmd2` (`run-this-one`) in another terminal, it works as expected (the `cmd1` process is stopped and removes the container, and the `cmd2` process runs successfully).

If I run `/path/to/test cmd2` in 2 terminals, it also works as expected (the 1st `cmd2` process is stopped and removes the container, and the 2nd `cmd2` process runs successfully).

**But not so good**: in the 2 cases above, sometimes the 2nd process stops with an error before the 1st removes the container (this can occur intermittently, probably due to a race condition).

**And it gets worse**: if I run `/path/to/test cmd1` in 2 terminals, both commands fail, although the 1st `cmd1` should run successfully (it fails because the 2nd `cmd1` removes the container in the cleanup).

I tried to put the cleanup in the `cmd:unique` command instead (removing from the other 2 places), so as to call only by the single process running, to avoid the problem above, but weirdly the cleanup is not called there, even if the trap is also defined there.

Comment: I don't know whether `run-this-one` sends a SIGTERM signal or a SIGKILL one; in the first case, you could just try to define a function such as `cleanup() { docker kill TODO; }`, then set it as a trap? i.e. `trap cleanup INT TERM`

Comment: @ErikMD From the perspective of `run-one` and `run-this-one` in my scenario they don't (and shouldn't) know if docker is running, nor the container name or id. The actual script is more complex than the demonstration I posted above (to make it easier to simulate the issue), and may run docker more than once, or none at all.

Comment: Furthermore, the script that is running, runs the command in the docker container until it ends, so trap would have to be triggered by the `run-this-one` command, and I would need to run a script that runs the `run-this-one` command, and it would still fail the first time, it would work only the 2nd time. I will see the feasibility to make every place that runs docker to use the same container name, which could work in this case, although it's not a very flexible solution.

Comment: I wasn't able to catch the error with `INT` and `TERM`, I was able to catch with `ERR`, but this is triggered on every error. I can put it only in the `run-this-one` command so that the container is destroyed after the error, then I can run it the 2nd time. Not a very good solution. If I trap the `run-one` command too, it works as expected if I run the `run-this-one` command, but if I run another `run-one` command instead (as in a cronjob), the container is removed when running the 2nd time, and breaks the one that was already running (that should keep running).

Answer (score 1):

Just to simplify your question, I would use this command to reproduce the problem:

```
run-one docker run --rm -it alpine sleep 10
```

As can be seen - either with `run-one` and `run-this-one` - the behavior is definitely not the desired one.

Since the command creates a process managed by `docker`, I suspect that the `run-one` set of tools is not the right tool for the job, since docker containers should not be killed with `pkill`, but rather with `docker kill`.

One relatively easy solution, is to embrace the way docker wants you to kill containers, and create your short `run-one` scripts that handle docker properly.

#### `run-one-docker.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "$#" -lt 2 ]]; then
  echo "Usage:   ./run-one-docker.sh NAME COMMAND"
  echo "Example: ./run-one-docker.sh temp alpine sleep 10"
  exit 1
fi

name="$1"
command=("${@:2}")

container_is_running() {
  [ "$( docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' "$1" 2> /dev/null)" == "true" ]
}

if container_is_running "$name"; then
  echo "$name is already running, aborting"
  exit 1
else
  docker run --rm -it --name "$name" "${command[@]}"
fi
```

#### `run-this-one-docker.sh`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "$#" -lt 2 ]]; then
  echo "Usage:   ./run-this-one-docker.sh NAME COMMAND"
  echo "Example: ./run-this-one-docker.sh temp alpine sleep 10"
  exit 1
fi

name="$1"
command=("${@:2}")

container_is_running() {
  [ "$( docker container inspect -f '{{.State.Running}}' "$1" 2> /dev/null)" == "true" ]
}

if container_is_running "$name"; then
  echo "killing old $name"
  docker kill "$name" > /dev/null
fi

docker run --rm -it --name "$name" "${command[@]}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't think the run-one version is needed because it already works as expected (and is the one I nuse in cronjobs, while the run-this-one is the one that the problem occurs, and I would run only if I ssh the server and want to make sure that the command I run is executed, stopping the corresponding cronjob, if any). I included the choes in docker run mainly to show the output `sleep ended inside...`, even though just a sleep, as you said, is actually a simpler demonstration.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think it will work for my use case, because the script could become very complex if I want to include options like entrypoint, volumes, logging driver and other options that I use, when docker handles it already. But this is not actually the main reason, after all I could handle that. The main reason is that I don't know if the script is running a docker container at that moment (I don't even know if it will run a container).

Comment: I make it only run a docker command in my post as a demo to make things simpler, but it can run docker more than once, or none at all, and it could not be running at the moment I run the command, but it might run after, making the behaviour unpredictable (with the possibility of running the task more than once at the same time, which **is** I want to avoid). Maybe podman could solve this specific issue, because it spawns child processes instead of sending the instructions to a daemon (I haven't tested yet, tough).